Advice on decomplecting and decoupling my tic tac toe implementation
I am hoping to find out what you think about my implementation of tic-tac-toe.
It is complete and working as expected with many tests, but the logic in the main module where I have the play-game main game loop is not great, and I am looking for feedback on potential ways to improve my code. I will share the relevant code and also a link to the repo it is in.
in main.clj:

(defn play-game 
  "This is the main game loop. Since the program is optimized/unlosable for the
    computer, technically only a draw or a loss may occur. Accompanied are tests,
    and any further testing is welcome and I can provide further testing upon request."
  [player-name]
  (println (str "Okay " player-name ", welcome to the game!"))
  (reset! state/game-state (assoc state/board-state :player-name player-name))
  (loop []
    (let [current-state @state/game-state]
      (console/print-current-board current-state (:moves-made current-state))

      ;is the game over? Loss or Draw Condition since win is impossible
      (if-let [{:keys [state next-state]} (state/check-game-over current-state)]
        (let [[new-stats play-again?] (console/handle-game-over-state next-state)]
          (if play-again?
            (do
              (reset! state/game-state (assoc state/board-state
                                        :stats new-stats
                                        :player-name player-name))
              (recur))
            new-stats))

        ;Continue game, player and computer input.
        (let [input (when (= (:current-player current-state) "X")
                      (console/handle-player-turn))
              {:keys [state next-state]} (ai/compute-next-game-state current-state input)]
          (reset! state/game-state next-state)
          (case state
            :invalid-move ;as opposed to invalid 'input' the form of input would is  
            (do           ;fine, but in this condition the board spot is taken.
              (println "Invalid move! Spot already taken.")
              (recur))

            :continue
            (recur)))))))

(defn -main
  "The entry point to the program. It first prints a heading and then takes
    user input simply for their name. After welcoming the player, it will
    invoke the main game loop. The game will exit and print a thank you
    message when the player has chosen not to stop playing."
  []
  (console/print-heading)
  (let [player-name (read-line)]
    (play-game player-name)
    (console/end-of-game-message true)))


in ai.clj:

(defn get-available-moves
  "Iterate through the 'open' board positions and return a destructured array
    of available positions based on their grid coordinates."
  [board]
  (->> (for [row (range (count board))
             col (range (count (first board)))]
         (when (state/legal-move? row col board)
           [row col]))
       (remove nil?)))

(defn evaluate-position
  "This function applies a score to the potential move being evaluated. A score
    of 0 inevitably continues the game and will lead to an updated board state,
    while a 1 or -1 signal the end of the game."
  [board player]
  (cond
    (= (state/check-winner board) player) 1
    (= (state/check-winner board) (if (= player "X") "O" "X")) -1
    (empty? (get-available-moves board)) 0
    :else 0))

(defn minimax
  "Minimax is a recursive algorithm that assesses a current board-state, and
    applies scores of either nil to each one (location),indicating the game will 
    progress, or otherwise declaring a winner. If a score 1 or -1 is returned,
    a position is not returned."
  [board player depth]
  (let [winner (state/check-winner board)]
    (if (or (zero? depth)
            winner
            (empty? (get-available-moves board)))
      [(evaluate-position board player) nil]
      (let [available-moves (get-available-moves board)
            scores-and-moves (for [[row col] available-moves]
                               (let [new-board (state/update-board-state board row col player)
                                     [score _] (minimax new-board
                                                        (if (= player "X") "O" "X")
                                                        (dec depth))]
                                 [(* -1 score) [row col]]))]
        (apply max-key first scores-and-moves)))))

(defn compute-next-game-state
  "This function calls the evaluate-and-update-game function, which will first take
   the player's input and update the game-state with their validated input. Minimax
   is called to caculate and the best move for the computer to execute. It returns
   the move that the ai made destructured into a row and column so that "
  [current-state input]
  (state/evaluate-and-update-game current-state
                                  (if (= (:current-player current-state) "X")
                                    input  ;Player's move
                                    (let [[_ [ai-row ai-col]] (minimax (:board current-state) "O" 9)]
                                      [ai-row ai-col]))))

in state.clj:

(ns tic-tac-cloj.state)

(def board-state
  {:board [[" " " " " "]
           [" " " " " "]
           [" " " " " "]]
   :moves-made 0
   :stats {:wins 0 :losses 0 :draws 0}
   :player-name nil
   :current-player "X"})


(defn check-winner
  "This part of the algorithm reviews the state of the board, iterating through
    all rows, and finally the diagnal axis of the board, determining whether 
    there are any filled lines across any one of 8 axis. If so it will return
    that particular array or nil"
  [board]
  (let [diag1 [(get-in board [0 0]) (get-in board [1 1]) (get-in board [2 2])]
        diag2 [(get-in board [0 2]) (get-in board [1 1]) (get-in board [2 0])]
        rows board
        cols (apply map vector board)
        all-lines (concat [diag1 diag2] rows cols)]
    (some (fn [line]
            (when (and (not= " " (first line))
                       (apply = line))
              (first line)))
          all-lines)))

(defn check-game-over [current-state]
  "This function takes the current state of the game and evaluates if there is a winner
   first by calling the check-winner function, and subsequently in the event that there
   have been 9 moves completed."
  (let [{:keys [board moves-made]} current-state
        winner (check-winner board)]
    (cond
      winner
      {:state :game-over
       :next-state (-> current-state
                       (assoc :winner winner)
                       (update :stats #(update % (if (= winner "X") :wins :losses) inc)))}

      (>= moves-made 9)
      {:state :game-over
       :next-state (-> current-state
                       (assoc :winner nil)
                       (update :stats #(update % :draws inc)))})))

(defn update-board-state
  "Update-board-state functions by taking appropriate symbol ('X' or 'O') into the 
    appropriate spot in the state vectors for both the player and computer."
  [board row col player]
  (if (legal-move? row col board)
    (assoc-in board [row col] player)
    board))

(defn evaluate-and-update-game
  [current-state [row col]]
  (let [{:keys [board current-player]} current-state
        new-board (update-board-state board row col current-player)]
    (if (= new-board board)
      {:state :invalid-move
       :next-state current-state}
      {:state :continue
       :next-state (-> current-state
                       (assoc :board new-board)
                       (update :moves-made inc)
                       (assoc :current-player (if (= current-player "X") "O" "X")))})))

I honestly think most of it is pretty reasonable and decent, but the big play-game function in my main.clj is troubling, and I both have difficulty understanding what exactly is wrong with it, and how I can improve and simplify it.
